# matching a pattern consisting sub-patterns with different levels of mismatch thresholds

Tags: regex, dna-sequence

I am analyzing a large list of DNA sequences to identify those that contain a specific pattern consisting of two sub-patterns, accounting for different levels of mismatches for each sub-pattern. Specifically, I want to allow a maximum of one mismatch for Sub-Pattern1 and a maximum of two mismatches for Sub-Pattern2. A mismatch can be substitution, insertion, or deletion with the cost of one.

For example, a pattern of interest is **AAA**TT**CCC**, with **AAA** and **CCC** as Sub-Pattern1 and Sub-Pattern2, respectively. That is,

```
Pattern: AAATTCCC
Sub-Pattern1: AAA
Sub-Pattern2: CCC
```

Example for substitution:
Given the input list of DNA sequences:

```
AAATTCCC
AGATTGGG
ACCTTCCG
ACCTTCGC
AAATTTTT
AAATTTTT
AGATTCGG
```

I need to identify sequences that match the pattern with the specified mismatch thresholds. The expected output for the input list is:

```
AAATTCCC
AGATTCGG
ATATTCTT
AAATTC
AAATTCC
AAATTC
AATTC
AAGATTCTTCC
```

What is the appropriate regex syntax to get the expected output in the above mentioned example?

***UPDATE:***

Example for substitution, deletion, and insertion in pattern of intrest:

Input:

```
AAATTCCC
AGATTGGG
ACCTTCCG
ACCTTCGC
AAATTTTT
AAATTTTT
AGATTCGG
AAATTC
AAATTCC
AAATTC
AATTC
AAATTCTTTTTT
AAGATTCTTCC
```

expected output:

```
AAATTCCC
AGATTCGG
ATATTCTT
AAATTC
AAATTCC
AAATTC
AATTC
AAGATTCTTCC
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

The trickier part of the problem is to match 2 `A`s out of the first 3 characters in any positions, which can be done by capturing what comes after the first 3 characters in a lookahead pattern, and then assert that what's captured follows the occurrence of 2 `A`s:

```
(?=...(.*)).?A.?A.?(?=\1)TT.{0,2}C.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lF9d4I/1

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. I have updated my example to clarify my question more.
the `(?=...(.*)).?A.?A.?(?=\1)` allows substitution only neither insertion or deletion.
`C.*` allows any character after C

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Jg6UV2/1